# Idea to sort (My)SQL results with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal.

Sort the results provided by MySQL depending on parameter passed by controller.

### The scenario.

There are a few controllers on my application and some of them bring to the user data from database.

When I access `~/Products/Compare?Id=1&OrderBy=lowestPriceToBiggest` I want to show the comparison of product with id `1` sorting by `lowestPriceToBiggest`.

To summarize, I want to make my procedure's `ORDER BY` behave according the value of parameter `OrderBy` passed by URL.

### Spotlight.

My `ProductsController` is:

```
public ActionResult Products(Nullable<int> id, string orderBy)
{
    List<Products> productsList = Build.ProductsList(id, orderBy);
    return View(productsList);
}
```

My query is:

```
Select product.Name As productName
From app_products As product
Where product.Id = 1
Order By product.Price Asc
```

As you can see, until now, there isn't communication between my C#'s code and SQL's code to sort the list of products. I'm stuck now. How can I covert something like `biggestPriceToLowest` provided by the parameter to SQL code? I mean, the `orderBy` parameter's returns me `biggestPriceToLowest` and I need to convert it to

```
[...]
Order By product.Price Desc
```

Can you see the *`Desc`*? How can I convert the string `biggestPriceToLowest` provided by the URL to `Desc`, to send as parameter to my procedure?

***Only to emphasize:*** without any manipulation, the `orderBy` parameter of my controller is sending `biggestPriceToLowest` (string) or `lowestPriceToBiggest` (string) to `Build.ProductsList()`, but I need to convert these strings into `Desc` or `Asc` respectively.

### What I've already thought about.

I thought to make a `switch` to convert each string into SQL code — but I do not know if it is a good practice or if what I'm doing it is the right/best way.

### Eventually, what is the question?

Based on my scenario, what do I have to make? A switch? There exists some trick that I do not have knowledge?

### Technical details.

I'm using C# + MVC 4 + Asp.Net + Razor Engine + MySQL.

Comment: can you not just order the List using Linq?

Comment: Yes, @NicholasKing — I can! Seriously, I do not thought this before. By the way, how can I change `biggestPriceToLowest` into List's sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Action I would do something like this and add the case statements as required

```
switch(orderBy) 
{ 
     case "priceASC": return productsList.OrderBy(x =>x.Price); 
     default: return productList 
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it would not be considered good practice dependant on scenario your using it in.

Comment: @Habib Performance question — that's why I like to post here, on Stack. Thanks about the information. Do you want to convert this comment into an answer?

Comment: @Habib I agree, but like I said as with anything it depends on scenario, I don't see anything inherently wrong with this approach though.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Performance questions are so overrated as Jeff Atwood has said hardware is cheap programmers are not http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html. Dependant on the size of productlist sorting it in the application vs db will be negligible

Comment: Got it, Nicholas. I'm using your solution. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if you are getting scaling issues just move your sql query to the Switch statement and issue the sql command from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ODATA to make the query:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/jj658971.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393623/OData-Services

you will make a call to a URL rest and get the result